# Wanting index.php to load when loaded

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have almost created a fully working dynamic page using PHP OOP. I have successfully created a working menu - that is when a menu item is clicked, relevant text is displayed on the page.  However, what I want is to have the home page text displayed by default and not solely clicking the Home link.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    <?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/Article.php');

//instanstiating the article class and ssigning it to a variable

$article = new Article;
//assigning the contents of the method called fetch_all to  the variable $articles
//this fetch_all method is inside the Articles class which is assigned to the above variable $article
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple PDO CMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
       
    <div class="container">
        
        <table class="topMenu">
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1 class="siteName">site name</h1>
                </td>
                
                <!--Displaying the articles using a foreach loop-->
                <?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>
                
                <td class="navItem">
                    
                    <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $article['id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['menuheader'];  ?></a>
                    
                </td>
                
                <?php } ;?>
                
            </tr>
            
        </table>
           
    </div>
    
    <p> this is where the time line will go</p>
    
    <?php 
    
        //instanstiating the article class and ssigning it to a variable
        $newArticle = new Article;

        //checking if the user clicked the menu link 
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                //the display the article content
                $id=$_GET['id'];

                $data=$newArticle->fetch_data($id);

            ?>
            <p><?php echo $data['bodytext']; ?></p>

            <?php

        } else {
           
        }
        ?>
    
    <p>This is where the footer will go</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So far I have tried: $id = 1; and using a redirect to index.php. Neither worked, the later due to 'to many redirects'.

I would like to keep the code I have used so far rather than redoing it again, so if you can help, please give me advice on this code.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a redirect at this point? If `$_GET['id']` is not set, then set `$id = 1;`, and proceed the same way after that, as you would have, if the value was passed in from the outside in the first place …

Comment: `$data=$newArticle->fetch_data($id);` should be outside of that `if`. You want to fetch data in any case, and not _only_ if `$_GET['id']` was set.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set the id to 1 (or what ever your home page is) if there aren't any id passed in the url. No need for the if-statement.

Here's how it can be done using the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php):

```php
$newArticle = new Article;

// Sets the id to what $_GET['id'] is set to if it exists, otherwise, set it to 1
$id   = $_GET['id'] ?? 1;

$data = $newArticle->fetch_data($id);
?>

<p><?php echo $data['bodytext'] ?? 'Page not found'; ?></p>
```

I also added in how you can show "Page not found" if `$newArticle->fetch_data($id)` didn't return anything.